# HTML Fade music on link

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I would like, when navigating away from the page, to execute a fade of a musical cue instead of cutting if off abruptly. It is okay with me if the fade adds a half second to the time needed to execute the link.

I have the following code that will execute a fadeout of a playing music cue.

```
<audio id="myAudio"
  <source src="./audio/pluto.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and

```
<script>
  function fadeAudio()
  {
    if (myAudio.volume > 0) 
    {
        myAudio.volume = Math.max(0, myAudio.volume - 0.05);
        setTimeout(fadeAudio, 20);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tested this code with a button, and it works fine (sometimes there is a bit of zippering, but I prefer it to an abrupt cutoff).

```
<button onclick="fadeAudio()">Try it</button>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to call and execute this fade before navigating away. I was looking at html's *onbeforeunload*, but that seems to be geared entirely to printing a warning prompt, with no way to insert my intervening fadeAudio() function.

Simply doing the following accomplished nothing:

```
<body onbeforeunload="fadeAudio()">
```

And this didn't work with *onunload* either.

I am thinking another approach would be to rewrite the links on the page to run the fadeAudio() function first. (It's more important to me that transitions between my pages sound nice than if the user decides to close or go elsewhere.) Perhaps this can be done via making a button and calling the fadeAudio and a linking function in sequence. But it seems there might also be a neater way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that kind of works:
(1) in the  link, one can call a function
(2) in the function, I first call the fadeAudio() function, then I call a setTimeout() function with 1000 ms time allotted to allow the fadeAudio() to complete
(3) then the setTimeout calls a window.open() method of the target link.

I'm going to be tweaking the various timings to see how far I can tighten this without adding too much zippering. It will definitely make things a little sluggish going from location to location on my site though.

Wouldn't it be nice if there was a way for the sound to just fade out in its own thread *while* the new page appears. If there is a way, I would love to know about it.

In the script tag:

```
  function linkToHome()
  {
      fadeAudio();
      setTimeout(openHome, 1000); 
  }

  function openHome()
  {
    window.open('index.htm','_self');
  }
```

The URL call in HTML:

```
  <a href="javascript:linkToHome()">Home</a>
```

Will probably try to figure out a way to paramaterize the above to allow the method or  tag to include the target URL.